# django save override on duplicated key error

Tags: django, forms

I'm overriding save method for modelForm

```
  def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                     
     userProfile = super(UserProfileForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)                                                              
     if self.cleaned_data.get('birth_year') :                                                                                      
          userProfile.birthDay=date(self.cleaned_data['birth_year'], self.cleaned_data['birth_month'], self.cleaned_data['birth_day'])           
     **userProfile.save(commit)** <- This is error!!!
     return userProfile
```

This is view.py

```
def user(request):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    if request.method=='POST':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.get_profile(), option='modify')                                                                                                                                                                            

        if form.is_valid():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            userProfile = form.save()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        form = UserProfileForm(instance = request.user.get_profile(), option='modify')                                                                                                                                                                                        

    return render(request,'profile/user.html', {'userProfileForm':form,})
```

But if I update my UserProfile, form.save() make error, for duplicated Key.

How Can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show us your UserProfile model along with its save method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save(commit)` will force an insert.

`commit` is a keyword argument.

`save(commit=commit)`